# Modify MainActivity variables depending on input from Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am building an application where I am using a `ListView`. Currently when the user clicks a row of the ListView, the following code executes. This code basically deletes some data concerned with the selected row. The code is a snippet from MainActivity.class.

```
//understanding this code is not crucial. list is the ListView, adapter is an 
//ArrayAdapter object and displayDataMap is a Hashmap object.

list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
    String key = adapter.getItem(position); //position of ListView row
    String data = displayDataMap.get(key);
    displayDataMap.remove(key);

  //"aqlpzaml" is used as a regex.
    String addressee = data.split("aqlpzaml")[1];
    long time = Long.valueOf(data.split("aqlpzaml")[0]);
    int finalID = Integer.valueOf(data.split("aqlpzaml")[3]);
    String dateTime = sdf.format(time);
    adapter.remove(addressee + " " + dateTime);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now I want that before deleting this data, the user is prompted with a `Dialog`, where he is asked if he is sure to make the changes.

I know how to create a `Dialog` and display it. But I don't know how to trigger change in the values of `adapter` and `displayDataMap` based on the `Dialog` input. I think if I'll use another class to create a `Dialog` object (using `DialogFragment`), then I won't be able to access the private variables of `MainActivity` class in the `setPositiveButton()` of that dialog.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert your Dialog creation in onItemLongClick and make the Adapter "adapter", "addressee" and "dateTime" final so you can access it in the setPositiveButton() method.

Cause i don't know how your Adapter is created it should look like this and in the same function as list.setOnItemLongClickListener or a class variable:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = ...
```

also your datamap:

```
final Hashmap<String, ...> displayDataMap = ...
```

And your function should look like this:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        final String key = adapter.getItem(position); //position of ListView row
        String data = displayDataMap.get(key);
        //"aqlpzaml" is used as a regex.
        final String addressee = data.split("aqlpzaml")[1];
        long time = Long.valueOf(data.split("aqlpzaml")[0]);
        int finalID = Integer.valueOf(data.split("aqlpzaml")[3]);
        final String dateTime = sdf.format(time);

        Builder dialog = new Builder(view.getContext());
        dialog
            .setMessage("Want to delete?")
            .setPositiveButton("delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    displayDataMap.remove(key);
                    adapter.remove(addressee + " " + dateTime);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        dialog.create().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks.
But I was wondering if there is a way we can use DialogFragment because I am under the impression that Android javadocs say that we shouldn't use Dialogs directly ?

Comment: If you want to reuse that dialog you can also use a DialogFragment and setArguments methods to pass adapter and displayDataMap. But i can't find a good reason why you shouldn't do it like this.